# Find profit or loss from same table for multiple user

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal is to find the difference of total selling amount and total buying amount (sell_amount - buy_amount)
So I am making 2 sql queries

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount) as buy_amount FROM orders WHERE type='buy' GROUP BY user


output table
─────┬─────────────
user | buy_amount
─────┼─────────────
1001 | 500
1002 | 200
```

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount) as sell_amount FROM orders WHERE type='sell' GROUP BY user
output table
─────┬─────────────
user | sell_amount
─────┼─────────────
1001 | 600
1002 | 150
```

To find the difference I have to make 2 query and calculate it with loops for all user
Is it possible to get a column `difference` ?

Imagined output table =

```
─────┬─────────────
user | difference
─────┼─────────────
1001 | 100
1002 | -50
```

Sample dataset

```
CREATE TABLE `sample_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `sample_order` (`id`, `user`, `type`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, 1001, 'buy', 500),
(2, 1002, 'buy', 200),
(3, 1001, 'sell', 600),
(4, 1002, 'sell', 150);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user, SUM(case when type='buy' then amount end) as buy_amount,
             SUM(case when type='sell' then amount end) as sell_amount,
             SUM(case when type='buy' then amount end) - SUM(case when type='sell' then amount end) as difference
FROM sample_order
GROUP BY user;
```

**The SQL CASE Statement:**
The CASE statement goes through conditions and returns a value when the first condition is met (like an if-then-else statement). So, once a condition is true, it will stop reading and return the result. If no conditions are true, it returns the value in the ELSE clause.

If there is no ELSE part and no conditions are true, it returns NULL.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

In your required query, there is no need for the ELSE part
simply we are checking the conditions (type = "buy" and "sell") in order to find the total amount of buying and sells with `SUM()` function of SQL for each `buy_amount` and `sell_amount`.
and similarly deducting the same to find a difference between two of them which gives you the complete required result.

**You can check an Example of same here:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5EmiBoLE8p3LnnTzeqSHw7/0

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT b.user, SUM(b.amount)-SUM(s.amount) as difference FROM orders b left join orders s ON b.user = s.user WHERE b.type='buy' AND s.type='sell' GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way

```
SELECT User, SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'buy' then amount * -1 ELSE amount  END) AS 'Difference' FROM sample_order GROUP BY User
```

If you want just a positive value for the difference you can also use ABS()

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(USER_IDD,OPER_SUMM, OPER_TYPE)
AS
(
   SELECT 1,100.00,'SELL' UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,200.00,'BUY' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,500.00,'SELL'
)
SELECT X.USER_IDD,X.SELL_SUMM-X.BUY_SUMM AS DIFFERENCES  FROM
(
  SELECT C.USER_IDD,
  SUM
  (
    CASE
     WHEN C.OPER_TYPE='SELL' THEN C.OPER_SUMM
     ELSE 0
   END
 )AS SELL_SUMM,
SUM
(
  CASE
   WHEN C.OPER_TYPE='BUY' THEN C.OPER_SUMM
   ELSE 0
  END
)AS BUY_SUMM
   FROM CTE AS C
   GROUP BY C.USER_IDD
 )X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select user, sum(case when type = 'buy' then amt else -amt end) as difference
from sample_order
group by user;
```

Comment: That's just addition & subtract. That OP can change accordingly.